# Ionic - Better way to implement

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am creating an app in phonegap for daily news, I am storing my news details to amozon s3 server.
So in my app home page i am displaying all news list. User can read news in both offline and online mode.
I stored amozon s3 file link in my database. So for fetch the news detail i called the s3 file and get its details.
When my app load i am fetching all news list and store it to my local database(sqllite). For getting all news details i am excuting all list in a loop(one by one) and hit a http request for fetch the every news details.
The problem is that if i have 500 news list, then each time it iterate to 500 time and call the http request 500 time. That decrease my application proformence.(Some time http request failed and i am getting few news list details and then user can not able to read news in offile mode).
Can You please tell me any better solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

That would have to depend on how you want your user experience to be. Would you want to enforce full internet connectivity on your apps or hybrid. Since majority of the users have internet connection, you linking the page to an existing news from the source site itself would be more feasible and less taxing on your server.

But if you still want to do hybrid ,you can consider the following:

For news, you would have to consider images/videos. 
You could store all text(news) inside your amazon server, in which u can download text data into your sqlite everyday or when user clicks on refresh button/news.

For images/videos, u can load it(from the news source itself) while the page(news info) is retrieved from ur sqlite. If it's offline, the text only news details would be available still.

Comment: is it ok to send 500  requests for news detail ?

Comment: No. Why not you wait for user to select before sending an request?

Comment: 1) battery-draining 2)internet data costly 3)waiting time to wait for 500 request too long.

Comment: then what you suggest for this please

Comment: Gather the news header and link into an object of a JSON file, u can store 500 links into one single json file in which u can pass around.